# How to search for a specific column name in data

Tags: r

So this is a bit strange, I am pretty new to R and facing this weird problem.
I have a data frame, and there is a column called `SNDATE` which is a combined value of two different columns.

I want to check if the data frame has a column named `SN`, if it doesn't I will split `SNDATE` to fill the `SN` column.

Here is the code

```
if(!('SN' %in% colnames(data))){
     #do some spliting here
}
```

Funny thing is, it keeps saying it's there, and the stuff in it never gets triggered. 
And when I do this:

```
print(data$SN)
```

It will print the value of `data$SNDATE`. So does R have some sort of lazy name filling or something? This is very strange to me.

Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
print(data$SN)
```

it works because `$` is using **partial name matching**.  For another example, try

```
mtcars$m
```

There is no column named `m`, so `$` partially matches `mpg`.  Unfortunately, this is not used in `%in%`, so you will need to use the complete exact column name in

```
if(!('SNDATE' %in% colnames(data))){
     #do some spliting here
}
```

You could insead use something along the lines of `pmatch()`

```
names(mtcars)[2] <- "SNDATE"
names(mtcars)[pmatch("SN", names(mtcars))]
# [1] "SNDATE"
```

So the `if()` statement might go something like this -

```
nm <- colnames(data)
if(!nm[pmatch("SN", nm)] %in% nm) {
    ...
}
```

Or even

```
if(is.na(pmatch("SN", names(data)))
```

might be better

Comment: That's my problem, I want to check if SN is in the data frame. R keep saying yes, it's there because SNDATE is there.

Comment: It doesn't say "yes it's a column name" , it partially matches a column name and gives you that column.  What do you want to do?  Do you want to use `SN` in the `%in%` call?

Comment: hmm okay. Ya that partial matching thing is totally new to me, and somehow makes me feel it's quiet a dangerous thing to have around :x I need to make the if statement to check for column SN so I know if I need to split the SNDATE to fill it up.  I will try with your answer above. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @GängTian - It is a dangerous thing.  Haha, try not to use it unless you have to.